# Custom container: @IBOutlets nil even though view is displaying correctly

Tags: ios, swift, iboutlet, uicontainerview

I have created a UIViewController. Within this view controller I have a container view.

In the code I instantiate the container view like so:

```
var answerButtons: AnswerButtonsViewController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    answerButtons = AnswerButtonsViewController()
    answerButtons.delegate = self

    println(answerButtons.name) // This prints out the correct string
    println(answerButtons.answerOne) // This prints out nil
    println(answerButtons.buttons) // This prints out an empty array

    retrieveSelectedCategory(selectedCategory!)
}
```

However the container view is definitely instantiate because within the container view class I set the background color of the UIButton's and this displays correctly within my app.

Here is the code from my container view:

```
@IBOutlet var answerOne: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var answerTwo: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var answerThree: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var answerFour: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var answerFive: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var answerSix: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var answerSeven: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var answerEight: UIButton!

var buttons: Array<UIButton> = []

var name = "Is this set"

var delegate: AnswerButtonsViewControllerDelegate?

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    addAnswerButtonsToArray()
    buttons.map(customiseButtons)
}

func addAnswerButtonsToArray() {
    buttons.append(answerOne)
    buttons.append(answerTwo)
    buttons.append(answerThree)
    buttons.append(answerFour)
    buttons.append(answerFive)
    buttons.append(answerSix)
    buttons.append(answerSeven)
    buttons.append(answerEight)
}

func customiseButtons(button: UIButton) {
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
    button.backgroundColor = GSNColor.veryLightGrayColor()

    var title: String! = button.titleLabel?.text
    title.replaceRange(title.startIndex...title.startIndex, with: String(title[title.startIndex]).capitalizedString)
    button.titleLabel?.text = title
}

@IBAction func answerButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    delegate?.answerButtonPressed(sender)
}
```

Also the IBAction of the buttons work.

So I can't understand why my property answerButtons is initiated and the name property is set ok. However the properties are nil when printed and the array empty. Yet the view is being displayed correctly.

Any insights would be much appreciated and if you need any more details please let me know.

**Edit**

Here is a picture of storyboard with the connections:

[image]

Comment: How did you create the IBOutlets? Are they actually connected to the buttons in the storyboard or xib?

Comment: Hey MirekE, I have added a picture showing the storyboard and the connections. Let me know if anything isn't clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controller embedded in the container view is instantiated at the same time that the controller with the container view is. You should not instantiate it yourself. You only need to get a reference to it. A controller in a container view is a child view controller of the controller whose subview is the container view. Instead of this,

```
answerButtons = AnswerButtonsViewController() // this creates another instance that you never use, and is never on screen
```

You should have this,

```
answerButtons = self.childViewControllers[0] as AnswerButtonsViewController
```

Comment: Hi rdelmar. I took a break and realised I was creating a new instance. Doh! However I wasn't sure how to get the instance in Swift. Your solution works like a charm. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you are just instantiating the view controller.You only get a reference to it.You have to instantiate the view controller using storyboard

```
let SB: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: StoryboardName, bundle: Bundle.main)
let VC = SB.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: StoryboardIdOfViewController)
if let _ = VC.view {
    //Do here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The IBOutlet's will be nil until the view is loaded. All you are doing is instantiating the container view controller, not displaying or loading the view.

The IBOutlet's won't be available until the AnswerViewController's `loadView` and `viewDidLoad` method's are called.

You can check:

```
if (answerButtons.isViewLoaded()) {

}
```

To see if the view is loaded. If you want the view to be loaded you'll either need to access the view property of the controller, or add the view to the view hierarchy as a subview.

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for the method. I have added it and can confirm that it doesn't enter the if statement. However I have added a viewDidLoad method to my AnswerButtonsViewController with a print statement and that gets printed before the other print statements. Also I thought the whole point of a container view was to hold the controller and its view. Why do you need to add the view?

Comment: Do you need to perform the embed segue? Or is it being performed?

Comment: Hey Jeff, thanks for the response. rdelmar answer sorted the problem. I was creating a new instance instead of getting the instance created by interface builder.